# Action Script 3.0. How to access MovieClip object from another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript, movieclip

So I have 2 classes **Main** and **Enemy**. In Enemy class I need to use variables that are declared in Main class.

Here is my **Main** class:

```
   public class Script extends MovieClip {
       var hero:MovieClip;
       var enemy:MovieClip; //These variables are only for example

       public function Game() {
                   hero.x = 100;
                   enemy.x = 200; // that's only example
   }
       function collisionDetected() {
                   enemy.hitBack(); // this is how I call hitBack function from Enemy class
   }
```

}

And here is my **Enemy** class:

```
public class Enemy extends MovieClip {
        private var count = 0;

        public function hitBack() {
            count = 0;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myEnterFrame);
        }

    private function myEnterFrame(e:Script)
    {
       if (count == 20) this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myEnterFrame);
       else 
       {
          count++;
          if (hero.x < enemy.x) { //here I need to use variables from Main class
            this.x -= 4;  
          }
           else {
            this.x += 4;  

          }
       }

    }
```

I got following **errors**:

```
1120: Access of undefined property hero.
1120: Access of undefined property enemy.
```

Answer (score 1):

You will either need to move that calculation out to the Main class, or you could also pass in the variables to the enemy class. Since your example is stripped down I'm not sure what is best in your case but I would lean towards moving the calculation out, assuming you have more than one enemy trying to do this.

```
public class Script extends MovieClip {
       var hero:MovieClip;
       var enemy:MovieClip; //These variables are only for example

       public function Game() {
                   hero.x = 100;
                   enemy.x = 200; // that's only example
                   this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
       }

       function collisionDetected() {
                   enemy.hitBack(); // this is how I call hitBack function from Enemy class
       }

       function enterFrame(e:Event){
            theEnemyMovieclipClass.myEnterCheck(hero,enemy);
       }




public class Enemy extends MovieClip {
        private var count = 0;

        public function hitBack() {
            count = 0;
        }

    public function myEnterCheck(hero,enemy)
    {
       if (count == 20) {
            // DO SOMETHING
       }
       else 
       {
          count++;
          if (hero.x < enemy.x) { //here I need to use variables from Main class
            this.x -= 4;  
          }
           else {
            this.x += 4;  

          }
       }

    }
}
```

This way if you had more than one you could loop through all of them and call the same method onEnterFrame.